# Websocket or WebRTC for chat application?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, webrtc, protocols, communication

1) websocket protocol can send and receive voice and video call?

2) web RTC can send and receive  text message ?

3) websocket or webRTC whom has more secure for use in chat application ?

4)  what is difference between video call and streaming video ?

5) websocket or webRTC whom are faster in communication ? ( send and receive text message , voice and video call )

6) can we use from websocket and webRTC in same application together ?

Thank you very much .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Websocket is a protocol which is based on HTTP, meaning that you can either send or receive any data via a websocket(wss), but the downside is that websocket can't capture video data.
2. You can use webrtc.datachannel to send or receive any data, webrtc.datachannel is based on P2P (Peer-to-peer). You can visit this [datachannel](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/datachannel/basic/).
3. You can use wss to make websocket more secure, plus you can choose wss to build a websocket connection. WebRTC is based on DTLS, so it is more secure(for packet sniffing). On the other hand, since WebRTC utilizes P2P, a user can trace another user's IP Address. You must use WebRTC via HTTPS or wss, or else it won't work.
4. Websocket needs a server, where WebRTC is a P2P connection, so WebRTC is faster.
5. Yes, you need a signal server to exchange SDP for WebRTC. You can use websocket to build the signal server.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question , websocket can not capture video means we with websocket can not send video call or video streaming ?

Comment: You can send video call or video streaming via websocket. 'websocket can not capture video stream' means websocket is just a transport protocol, not a tool which capture video streaming.